# Predicting the sum of two doubles

Tags: c#, javascript, math, double, computer-science

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

This is going to be a very rudimentary comp-sci question. Consider the following C# (the same holds true for JS, I assume it's how math works with doubles in general).

```
var i = .01;
i+=.01; //i=.02
i+=.01; //i=.03
i+=.01; //i=.04
i+=.01; //i=.05
i+=.01; //i=.0600000000005 (I may have added/missed a few 0s in there)
i+=.01; //i=.07
i+=.01; //i=.08
i+=.01; //i=.09
i+=.01; //i=.0999999999992 (I may have added/missed a few 9s in there)
```

So, what's happening and how can I accurately predict the sum of i+.01?

Comment: Read this and see if it helps: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? If the decimal value of low significance digits matter to you, you should not use `double` in the first place. Use `decimal` or similar constructs.

Comment: @CodesInChaos My goal was to get every hundredth interval between 0 and x. I worked around it by doing some division, but I want to understand how math works with doubles.

JonSkeet, taking a look now. Thanks.

Comment: This probably is a duplicate, I just couldn't come up with a way to phrase it to find a result that explained it. Jon Skeet's link got me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double isn't just a way to get decimal points for your number. It uses floating point math. [This article by Pete Becker](http://www.petebecker.com/js/js200006.html) does a good job of explaining how that works.